# Apply mark selection across multiple worksheets which are related (have same dimensions) via Tableau JavaScript APIs

Tags: javascript, tableau-api

I have embedded three viz from same dashboard,on the dashboard they were available via tabs, so after embedding those vizs in my webpage, if mark selection is done on one viz then it should affect other vizs or worksheets present on the webpage, so how would I know if marks data is applicable to certain worksheet so that I can apply the selectMarksAsync method with marks data to the certain worksheet?

Or is there a way to get field names from worksheet which are associated with mark selection, same as getFiltersAsync() method, so if I get the field names associated with the marks selection for worksheet, then I can check if current selected marks field names are available in another worksheet's marks field name, then I can apply the selectMarksAsync for that worksheet.

Comment: @halfar thanks for the edit, by any chance could you help me out with the issue? or any one you know might help me? can you forward this question to them please?

Comment: can no one answer this question? can no one help me out? is this stackoverflow for?no answers?i dont think so